# WinUI3: Published exe throws XamlParseException

Tags: c#, winui-3

The program works when starting from Visual Studio. It also starts from the Debug directory.

However, when I use the publish command in Visual Studio or dotnet publish from the command line, an Exception occurs.

```
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException: XAML parsing failed.
   at WinRT.ExceptionHelpers.<ThrowExceptionForHR>g__Throw|20_0(Int32 hr)
   at ABI.Microsoft.UI.Xaml.IApplicationStaticsMethods.LoadComponent(IObjectReference _obj, Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)
```

I have tried all the different settings, Debug/Release, Self-contained, Single file, ReadToRun, but the result is the same.

Currently I am using

```
<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.22000.0</TargetFramework>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.4.230822000" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.756" />
```

Comment: Does the error appear when you publish or when you run the published result?

Comment: When I start the exe from file explorer. During publish, no error is shown.

Comment: Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information? [Is your application unpackaged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/preview-experimental-unpackaged-tutorial?tabs=csharp-dotnet-preview3)?

Answer (score 0):

In this end, the error was caused by our own .props/.targets file.

`<CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets>OurCustom.targets</CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets>`

Instead, combine the already defined variable with your custom targets file:

`<CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets>OurCustom.targets;$(CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets)</CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets>`

Apparently, publish sets the CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets and we overwrote that property. The above solution worked.

Comment: What is "the above solution"?

Comment: @Dent7777 I highlighted the change in more detail, but I doubt many people are having this exact problem.